# PHP Categories Selection during registration

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a list of categories in mysql database . I want users to select the categories they want to pick at signup page . Can you guys give me your ideas how can i achieve this goal ? .

I want to display all available categories ,which i can pull into any of this like drop down, select box and simple page etc . i can use multiple select option two but i don't like that . i need some thing where user can pick categories , and then the also have ability to remove them if they mistakenly choose wrong , i also limit them to just choose 2 categories , Then finally i want that categories selection will save by id in there profile database(which i can do ) .

I have couple of ideas .

first idea is to put one select box on right side and fetch all categories from database then in center add two button "ADD" and "REMOVE" and then after them add another empty textarea box where its display user categories he add by clicking on "ADD" button. i hope u understand my idea .

can u help ?

Comment: Make another table that matches the ID of the user with the ID of the category.  Then use INNER JOIN when trying to query it.

Comment: with what exactly you need help here ? database design/queries/jquery code/php code/forms?

Comment: I use div not table , which user id u talking about ? its a user signup page not some thing for registered user . INNER JOIN ? can you explain more about or paste a example code thanks

Comment: I have PHP mysql database and i can use jquery/simple javascript / and any thing that compatible with browsers . i have tow table one is categories with id catname etc and usertable with id userid userpass usersemail usercat_id etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with following ides

First when users select categories and submit button then you want insert that categories id in category column in user table.

Second when user login then fetch only that categories which store in users category field.

i think u understand my solution.